Ensure the right friction in wood mechanism (vertical hanging sliding bolt)
I'm building a gate out of plywood (18mm thick) and fir slats (20x30mm). The gate will feature a kind of sliding bolt mechanism: one of the slats (the blue one in the picture) is taller than the other ones and is allowed to move up and down through holes in the upper and lower plywood panels.
This mechanism should be easily operated by an ordinary adult without applying a ton of force, and the slat should stay up by friction when lifted up.
How can I ensure this, and prevent the mechanism to get loose on the long run due to wood wearing for the frequent rubbing?

Edit: Based on the feedback, I realize I should provide more context:

The plywood panels are 18mm thick and make up the top and bottom parts of the gate frame.
The fir slats (20x30mm) form the vertical elements, including the sliding bolt mechanism.
The dimension of the whole gate is around 95x120cm.
The gate will be placed indoors, by a staircase, to prevent crawling creatures from descending the stairs. It’s intended to be a temporary solution, lasting a few years at most.

My priorities are:

Minimalistic design to keep the gate easy to build for a beginner.
Cost-effectiveness.
Sturdiness for the intended use.


I don’t think what you are asking is possible.
There are indeed cases where a wooden post needs to hold itself with friction. A planing stop in a traditional workbench comes to mind. But it is fit so tightly that it has to be adjusted with a mallet.
The problem is that there is quite a narrow range for that magical level of friction required for effortless adjustment with no slippage. If the wood shrinks or expands with humidity changes, the post will slip or become harder to move respectively. (This is even worse outdoors, but given your materials I am assuming this is an indoor project?)
I would recommend changing the mechanism. A few ideas:

The post in question can be a cylindrical rod with a small cross piece that passes through a round hole with extra cutouts on each side. You move the rod up and then turn it 90 degrees so that it does not fall.
You could use a metal latch, perhaps a very long one.

I would also recommend replacing the plywood with regular fir slats (thicker than 18mm). That way you don’t need to deal with ugly edges and also the gate is less likely to sag.

Thank you so much for your insights! I hadn’t even considered the issue of wood shrinking and expanding, great point. Your suggestions about using a cylindrical rod or a metal latch make a lot of sense. However, I’m not sure I’ll be able to source those materials or execute such design with my current tools and skills.
I’m now wondering if making larger holes and glueing insulation foam strips around their edges might do the job.

@etuardu Yeah, using some kind of foam should work. But if you have enough skill to make a square hole in plywood, I am sure the other options are within reach :) You could also search for “baby gate latch” in your area.

It is not clear what parts are plywood, what is fir, and what the mechanism is made of (wood? steel?) but any way you look at it, it is unlikely that the lock/latch will stay up over time on its own.  What the mechanism needs is another arm such as the one keeping the lock from raising too high (below the top rail) only positioned at 90 degrees so that it can move above the top rail (through a slotted hole in the top rail), set at a height to hold the mechanism high enough, and then rotate to rest on the top rail.
BTW, your diagram shows the rails and posts as very thin and would only work at those sizes if they were metal.  Also, plywood is not recommended for exterior use and will fail over any extended time period.

P.S. didn’t see your answer while writing, you beat me to it with both suggestions (turning in a slotted hole and getting rid of plywood)!

@stanch I'll give you this one, so voted you up

oh thanks @Ashlar!

Thanks for your comments, I've edited the question to add more context!
